# How to check if int is not null

Tags: c#

i am trying to get data from database and i got stuck on the last line. BestSellerRating is int and I am not sure what to do here. I need bestSeleltRating to be higher than 0 and not null value. "The result of expression is always true since a value of type int is never equal to null of type int"

```
var articles = (from a in _db.Articles
                join articleRating in _db.ArticleRatings on a.Id equals articleRating.ArticleId
                where a.IsDeleted == false
                      && a.IsFinished
                      && a.IsSubmited
                      && a.BestsellerRating > 0
                      && a.BestsellerRating != null
```

Comment: Change `BestSellerRating`'s type to `int?` which means "nullable int", and you thus can assign and check it for `null`

Comment: In addition to what Alex just said, you can check the `HasValue` property on an `int?` to see if it's null.

Comment: I'm not on my dev machine to try it quickly ... But, if you define a int as nullable int?, can't you check to see if it's null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I need bestSeleltRating to be higher than 0 and not null value - actual question being asked.**

**He is not asking how to make the int nullable.**

Below you are checking if a.BestsellerRating > 0 and a.BestsellerRating != null.

You only need a.BestsellerRating > 0. It will never be null and this condition will always check it's higher than 0.

The inverse of this would be a.BestsellerRating == 0

```
var articles = (from a in _db.Articles
            join articleRating in _db.ArticleRatings on a.Id equals articleRating.ArticleId
            where a.IsDeleted == false
                  && a.IsFinished
                  && a.IsSubmited
                  && a.BestsellerRating > 0
                  && a.BestsellerRating != null
```

Answer (score 0):

Databases and their Query results have a different way to anotate null, so `!= null` will not work.

It can vary on the specific Database and specific set of Database Access classes you use, but generally it maps to the DBNull class:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull

Of course we are also dealing with LINQ and possibly LINQ to SQL here, so it can be something entirely different yet again.